# Conditional formatting based on date to expire

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting

In SharePoint O365, in the modern experience, I have a list of training certificates that have an expiration date of one year from date taken.

I would like to use conditional formatting to create a status column that shows me the certificate is one of these:

1. **Current**, green background - taken sometime within the last 10 months.
2. **Expiring**, Orange background - Taken 11 or 12 months ago.
3. **Expired**, Red background - date past one year ago

I have done this for another list using the status of the request of whether it was approved or rejected but when it comes to dates I have found it rather difficult to get an example even close to what I am looking for. I used the formatting wizard that is not built in but it only compares to todays date and I can't use the date of a field.

**THE ANSWER:**

[image: picture of the working status JSON formatting]

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= @now - 26297460000 ,'green', (if(@currentField > @now - 31556952000, '#F07440','red'))"
  },
  "children" :[
   {
   "elmType": "span",
   "txtContent" : "=if(@currentField >= @now - 26297460000 ,'Current', (if(@currentField > @now - 31556952000, 'Expiring','Expired'))",
   "style": {
    "color": "white"
   }
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understood, you want to display text like 'expired', 'expiring','current' instead of date. Extending jerry's answer, you can use below

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= @now - 25920000000 ,'green', (if(@currentField >= @now - 31104000000, '#ffa59b','red'))"
  },
  "children" :[
   {
   "elmType": "span",
   "txtContent" : "=if(@currentField >= @now - 25920000000 ,'Current', (if(@currentField >= @now - 31104000000, 'Expiring','Expired'))",
   "style": {
    "color": "white"
   }
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The colors and dates were a little off but I got it!  This made a LOT more sense than what I was messing with!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON to do the work. use the JSON code below

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= @now - 25920000000 ,'green', (if(@currentField >= @now - 31104000000, '#ffa59b','red'))"
  }
}
```

Reference:
http://thebaretta.blogspot.com/2018/08/sharepoint-online-conditional.html

Comment: THANKS!  That example and source REALLY helped me understand a little bit more about JSON and dates with the conditional formatting!!