# Automatically update column based on date

Tags: list, column-formatting

Hopefully, somone can provide a bit of assistance.

The below question has been previously submitted and answered,  but I cannot find it.

I have a column name, [status], that has two options, "open" and "closed".
Another column holds a future closing date.
I am trying to see if it is possible to automatically change [status] column from "open" to "closed" when the future closed date has passed.
If the date has not passed, then the [status] field should show "open".

Answer (score 0):

You can create scheduler flow/power automate that will run on daily basis which will check if the date column value is less than today' date and status is Open then change the status to Close
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Harminder's correct suggestion, there is another way, if you only wish to show the closed or open message. Also, I believe that the question you are talking about should be the below: [Conditional formatting based on date to expire](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265160/conditional-formatting-based-on-date-to-expire)

If not, the answers show a way of solving your problem with column formatting using JSON syntax in order to evaluate date fields.